# Orchard CMS ContentQuery with N-to-N relation

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

In my project I've implemented N-to-N relation between records using [this tutorial](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations) on OrchardProject web-site. I have 2 parts: `MaterialPart` & `CategoryPart` and association record.

**Material part**

```
public class MaterialPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    public MaterialPartRecord() {
        Categories = new List<ContentMaterialCategoryRecord>();
    }
}

public class MaterialPart : ContentPart<MaterialPartRecord> {
    public IEnumerable<CategoryPartRecord> Categories {
        get { return Record.Categories.Select(cmcr => cmcr.CategoryPartRecord); }
    }
}
```

**CategoryPartRecord**

```
public class CategoryPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    ...
}

public class CategoryPart : ContentPart<CategoryPartRecord> {
    ...
}
```

**association record:**

```
public class ContentMaterialCategoryRecord {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MaterialPartRecord MaterialPartRecord { get; set; }        
    public virtual CategoryPartRecord CategoryPartRecord { get; set; }        

}
```

Now I need to select `MaterialItems` which are linked to certain category. So far I have this method to extract them. It works but I'm not sure that it is correct way to do this.

```
public IEnumerable<MaterialPart> GetMaterialsByCategory(int catId) {

    var cs = new CategoriesService(_oServices);

    CategoryPartRecord cat = cs.GetItem(catId).Record;

    return _oServices.ContentManager
             .Query(VersionOptions.Latest, _contentType)
             .Join<CommonPartRecord>()
             .OrderByDescending(cpr => cpr.PublishedUtc);
             .List()
             .Where(ci => ci.IsPublished())
             .Select(ci => ci.As<MaterialPart>())
             .Where(mp => mp.Categories.Contains(cat));        // < ---- ?    
}
```

So my question is: what is correct way to select `materials` for required category, which produces optimal SQL query, as we simply need to `inner join` associated record table with required `CategoryPartRecord_Id`  field value.

thaks!

Comment: Can you explain why you're not using taxonomies?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I've already explained in previous question about breadcrumbs :) you always say about taxonomies as it is panacea for all tasks.

Comment: Well, pardon me if I don't keep track of who said what on all the questions I answer, especially if there is no link to them. I always bring up taxonomies when there is a clear use case. You are re-implementing categories, which is *exactly* what taxonomies were designed for. So why aren't you using them?

Answer (score 0):

In case, of M : N with pairing object, we can use QueryOver and subquery. The biggest benefit would be, that we recieve the plain set of material Items, which we can use for paging (Take(), Skip())

```
var session = ... // get curretn session

CategoryPartRecord category = null;
ContentMaterialCategoryRecord pair = null;
MaterialPartRecord material  = null;

var subquery = QueryOver.Of<ContentMaterialCategoryRecord>(() => pair)

    // now we will join Categories to be able to filter whatever property
    .JoinQueryOver(() => pair.CategoryPartRecord, () => category)

    // here is the filter
    // there could be IN, >= <= ...
    .Where(() => category.ID == 1)
    // or
    .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.category.ID).IsIn(new[] {1, 2, 3})
    ...

    // now we will return IDs of the Material we are interested in
    .Select(x => pair.MaterialPartRecord.Id);


// finally the clean query over the Materials... 
var listOfUsers = session.QueryOver<MaterialPartRecord>(() => material  )
    .WithSubquery
        .WhereProperty(() => material.Id)
        .In(subquery)
    // paging
    .Take(10)
    .Skip(10)
    .List<MaterialPartRecord>();
```

So, this will produce the most effective SQL Script, with one subselect, and clean select from material table

NOTE: similar stuff could be done even with LINQ. But QueryOver is NHibernate most native way I'd say. Anyhow, the principe - subquery to filter by category, and main query to load materials will remain the same. Only ONE SQL Select call

Comment: thanks for your answer! as I understand this is a direct way to use `NHibernate` without all of these **Orchard CMS** `ContentQueries` stuff and so on?

Comment: Yes. ;) Not sure if this is what you want, sorry, do not know Orchard... But NHibernate way would be this, I'd say ;)